# Scrollbar pops up in container div in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, scrollbar

I've got a weird IE bug.  I have a bunch of pages that use a near identical template to show content.  In each page, there are 3 master containers: header, content, and footer.  The content div is separated into 2 other divs; 1 an image container, the other an ul.  On 3 of the 9 pages that all use the same code and template, a vertical scrollbar pops up on the ul div in ie9.  The other 6 pages don't have the vertical scrollbar.

I've tried changing the content container div to "position: relative" from "position: absolute" and that didn't work.  I've set the overflow, in the body tag in both the css header on the pages and the master stylesheet, to both hidden and auto, that didn't work.  I checked the code to make sure there weren't any errant tags, everything is clean.

Feel free to check out one pages if you have ie9, you can find the other ones by going to "film" and clicking on A Zombie Invasion and Chasing The White Dragon:
http://www.afterlightpictures.com/101.html

The container div is #films, the image div is #largeposter, and you can tell which one is the ul in the code below.  Let me know what I may be doing wrong or if this is another example of how wretched IE is.

```
#films {
    width: 70%;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 180px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

#largeposter  {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: left;
}

ul#info  {
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    display: list-item;
    width: 60%;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking how to remove the scroll bar?

Two ways I removed the scrollbar on your #films element:

add `height:100%` to your #films css

or you could:

remove `overflow:auto;` from #films css

Comment: That fixed the problem.  I'm still learning all this.  Thanks a lot Marklar!